# Facebook token in relation with Session

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, session, oauth-2.0

I have this function for facebook

```
public function link2(){
        global $config;
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => $config['facebook_appId'],
              'secret' => $config['facebook_secret'],
              'cookie' => true
        ));
        return $facebook;
    }
```

then I do this to get the token

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'])){
            $accesstoken = $_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'];
        }else{
            $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        }
```

and store it in DB, but after I logout and login again and make another call for ALBUMS I get error

```
A user access token is required to request this resource
```

i am doing `session_destroy` in my logout.php file, I am wondering how session is related to this , If i change my logout.php file to just unset userId variable then call works for me.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you confirm token saved to database? And how do you set back the access token to Facebook object? A little bit more of your code can help you to get answer.

Comment: @m_poorUser yes it is saved to DB,"how do you set back the access token to Facebook object?  I am not doing this, not sure what is this

Comment: I meant how do you use access token you saved the database after logout and login again?

Comment: @m_poorUser query the DB and get the token then do this
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => $config['facebook_appId'],
              'secret' => $config['facebook_secret'],
              access_token=>$tokenFROMDB
        ));

Comment: First delete access token from db, login and print $accesstoken. Log out, login again and print $tokenFROMDB. Compare them.

Comment: @m_poorUser they are same

Comment: @m_poorUser point is anything related to session when we get the tokens?

Comment: I don't think it is related to session because when you login and get access token first time, it is stored in the session, you are using it. If you destroy session, token is gone and pulled from database next time user logins right? So if you have a problem when you destroy the session then it has to be related something else. Session does exactly what it should according to your scenario.

Comment: I think you are facing same problem with mine problem. Do you used a cutom function for starting session in which you set the parameter for related to session.

Comment: @HimalyaVashistha yes

Comment: @user1765876 I think you have to try accessing user from a page where no session has been started and after that run your script. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just Follow these steps. you may need to get offline access token.

**1.** You will own App Name, App URL, App ID, and App Secret get access code, go to:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=Your_App_ID&redirect_uri=Your_App_URL&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access

after you click; your browser will be redirect to Your_App_URL with additional URL attribute, it will look something like:

Your_App_URL?code=long_facebook_code

**2.** get offline access token, go to :

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=Your_App_ID&redirect_uri=Your_App_URL&client_secret=Your_App_Secret&code=long_facebook_code

the page will display something like

access_token=123456789|99bdea74e40ecc75530b7c45-132456798|dTntC8lVyR84eBxK1TS9ws2s_s0

Note: make sure there are no word “expire=” in the end of the token (the bold text) copy your offline token (only the bold text) and use it, it permanent token and never change event if you change your application name.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you store the user access token in a session at all? The whole point of session data is temporary storage.

You can just save the token to the database during the login and read it from there every time you call `$facebook = new Facebook( ...`

It will be much easier if you store it in one place only.

The second point is, you cannot expect that the user uses a logout button. If the user just closes the browser and kills his or her cookies, the session will not be destroyed but no one can access it anymore. So the only thing that logout should do, is to destroy the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check and retrieve access token if exists for current user
$atfromdb = mysql_query("......"); 

if(isset($_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'])){
     $accesstoken = $_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'];
}else if( strlen($atfromdb) > 0 ){
     $accesstoken = $atfromdb;
}else{
     $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'])){
   $accesstoken = $_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'];
}else{
   $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
}
```

If this is the only code you have to assign `$accesstoken`, then `$accesstoken` will be undefined after logging out. `session_destory()` removes all keys stored in `$_SESSION`. So the `isset()` will return `false`. Next, `$facebook->getAccessToken()` only checks to the see if the token exists as a query string parameter; since the token is not being sent (it only gets sent after someone is redirected from Facebook), therefore `$accesstoken` is undefined.

A quick fix would be to set the session key as it existed before. Directly after your authentication code, set the session key using the user's data from your database. Such as:

```
$_SESSION['fb_'.$config['facebook_appId'].'_access_token'] = $user_from_database['his_stored_access_token'];
```